# Update a local repository with changes from a GitHub repository? NOT "git pull origin master"

Tags: ruby, git, github

I have created a CLI application for a friend of mine written in Ruby. In order to be useful, this application needs to be updated weekly, which I will do by pushing the changes to GitHub. My friend is the furthest thing from tech-savvy and is incapable of following the steps in order to pull the changes from a GitHub repository.

Is there an easier way for my friend to update their local version of the application each week? The solution might not involve GitHub at all, but I can't think of one.

Thanks in advance for any solutions or suggestions.

Comment: Make your application to update itself with e.g. https://github.com/piotrmurach/github

Comment: Giving a CLI tool to a tech-clueless person? What can go wrong? :)

Comment: You can write a script which download master.

Comment: Ha true Sergio. Might just create a web application instead. Thanks for your input guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to execute a system call at the beginning of your application. 
like:

```
# some_script.rb

# git repo initialization (if needed)
# system('git init . && git remote add ...')
system('git pull origin master')

p 'main ruby logic'
```

Comment: Can’t believe it was that simple. system(‘git pull’) is all I needed. Thanks